# Modifying Latex of Document in the PDF of Latex Editor

Tags: editors, pdfsync, tagged-pdf

Is there any opensource Latex editor which allows us to edit the latex content from the PDF (created using tex) itself. It will be useful when modifying the Latex document. It should pop the Latex box of the PDF element when clicked.

Synctex highlights the Latex code in the latex editor, I want the same to be shown in a box beside PDF element in a editable box.

Is it possible in a normal Latex document? or Does it need the PDF to be Tagged completely?

Using Adobe software, I can only edit the PDF element and not the Latex of it.

Comment: Long answer: No. There are no LaTeX editable source on the PDF (unless you attach the source file, but that is another story).

Comment: the latex source is not in the pdf, so clearly if you only have the pdf you can not see or edit the latex source. however synctex allows the pdf view to be synchronised with the source so clicking on the pdf scrolls the source editor to a matching line.